# Upload a video to youtube api and change the default title

Tags: php, zend-framework, yii

I am using YII and ZEND framework and I'm trying to change the title from a youtube video uploaded using zend framework but it doesn't work using the $_POST['title']... How can I set that using the posted title that was set by the user.

```
$video->setVideoTitle('Your video title');
$video->setVideoDescription('Description of the video');

$video->setVideoCategory('People'); 
$video->SetVideoTags('apps');
$handler_url     = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken';
$token_array     = $yt->getFormUploadToken($video, $handler_url);
$token          = $token_array['token'];
$post_url     = $token_array['url'];
$next_url      ='http;//my-next-url/';
```

and the form is:

```
<form name="catveh4" action="<?php echo $post_url ?>?nexturl=<?php echo $next_url ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Title</label><input type="text" name="title" />
    <label>Description</label><textarea name="desc"></textarea>
    <label>Tags</label><input type="text" name="tags" />
    <label>Category</label><input type="text" name="cat" />
    <input name="file" type="file" class="CS"/> <br />
    <input name="token" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $token ?>" />
    <input name="flag4" type="hidden" value="1">
</form>
```

Comment: to be more specific, when i say: $video->setVideoTitle($_POST['title']); it throes an error message saying something like the title isn't set properly, or something like that...

Comment: See what exactly you are passing to setVideoTitle() as parameter. Dump the parameter.

Comment: "Something like the title isn't set" isn't a helpful error message